# Routes are not available in RSpec integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webrat

I am following the examples in the [Rails Tutorial website](http://railstutorial.org/) and I'm having issues getting the integration tests to work. Specifically the example at listing 8.20 in [section 8.4.2](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec%3afailed_signup) in the tutorial.

At the **visit signup_path** line of code below I get the following error: "undefined local variable or method `signup_path'"

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Users" do
  describe "signup" do
    describe "failure" do
      it "should not make a new user" do
        visit signup_path
        fill_in "Name", :with => ""
        fill_in "Email", :with => ""
        fill_in "Password", :with => ""
        fill_in "Confirmation", :with => ""
        click_button
        response.should render_template("users/new")
        response.should have_selector("div#error_explanation")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

[Here's the full test file on github](http://github.com/paulyoder/RailsTutorial/blob/4daeb47d33392e9970d99b47c0b7bc0d522260e5/spec/requests/users_spec.rb)

**However, if I run all the tests at once, then I do not get the error.** The error only happens when I run that individual test.

My project can be viewed on github [here](http://github.com/paulyoder/RailsTutorial/tree/4daeb47d33392e9970d99b47c0b7bc0d522260e5)

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of a struggle I've realized this isn't an ID at all (at least in Rails 3.0.3), rather a class, named `id_error_explanation`.

Fixed with replacing the last bit with:

`response.should have_selector('div.id_error_explanation')`.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to change the test according to listing 8.21. The test would then look like this:

**spec/requests/users_spec.rb:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Users" do
  describe "signup" do
    describe "failure" do
      it "should not make a new user" do
        lambda do
          get signup_path
          fill_in "Name", :with => ""
          fill_in "Email", :with => ""
          fill_in "Password", :with => ""
          fill_in "Confirmation", :with => ""
          click_button "Sign up"
          response.should have_selector("div#error_explanation")
        end.should_not change(User, :count)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Eliminating the line `response.should render_template('users/new')` gets rid of the error I was getting, `@request must be an ActionDispatch::Request`, but the response page is empty. Is this example incorrect or obsolete as it stands in the tutorial?